# Data.table with cor.test by group

Tags: r, data.table

When I use `data.table` to compute correlations for each group with the cor.test function, it works fine for the default method (which is "pearson") but not for "spearman". I receive a `data.table` error.

```
library("data.table")
dd <- data.table(group=sample(letters[1:3], 50, replace=TRUE), x=rnorm(50), y=rnorm(50))
head(dd)
## group          x            y
## 1:     c  0.1808595  2.124721051
## 2:     a  0.2492086  0.112128546
## 3:     b -1.6392331 -1.823208890
## 4:     c  0.6605648  0.981215691
## 5:     c -0.4625216 -0.008350339
## 6:     b -0.2747395  1.045594928
dd[ , cor.test(x, y), by=group]  # works
dd[ , cor.test(x, y, method="spearman"), by=group]  # does not work
## Error in `[.data.table`(dd, , cor.test(x, y, method = "spearman"), by = group) : 
## Column 2 of j's result for the first group is NULL. [...]
```

Does anyone have any idea of a way to use cor.test by group with `data.table` that does not result in error? Or, if this is not anything fix-able by `data.table` at all because it has to do with the guts of cor.test here, any other comparable (data.frame, dplyr) way of using spearman cor.test by group that works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because the `parameter` element returned in the list result of `cor.test` for `method="spearman"` is `NULL`, which causes data.table to freak out.

The error message returned states this pretty explicitly:

> Column 2 of j's result for the first group is NULL. [...]

Just drop column 2 from the result then, and you'll be set.

```
dd[ , cor.test(x, y,method="spearman")[-2], by=group]

#   group statistic   p.value   estimate null.value alternative   ...    
#1:     c      2060 0.6263233  0.1043478          0   two.sided   ...
#2:     a       262 0.5762578 -0.1909091          0   two.sided   ...
#3:     b       650 0.5667271 -0.1607143          0   two.sided   ...
```

Comment: Can you explain the [-2] syntax? That does not seem to be the usual way to drop a column, but to exclude an element in a vector.

Comment: @boethian - `[-n]` can be used to drop a part of many R objects. A column in a data.frame, an item in a list (as is being done here, as `cor.test` returns a list), a single value in a vector, a row or column in a matrix ( with `[-n,]` or `[,-n]` ) etc etc. It's fairly common.