# For Loop for Correlations

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, correlation

I am wanting to get correlation values between two variables for each county.

I have subset my data as shown below and get the appropriate value for the individual Adams county, but am now wanting to do the other counties:

```
    CorrData<-read.csv("H://Correlation 
     Datasets/CorrelationData_Master_Regression.csv")
     CorrData2<-subset(CorrData, CountyName=="Adams")
     dzCases<-(cor.test(CorrData2$NumVisit, CorrData2$dzdx, 
      method="kendall"))
dzCases
```

I am wanting to do a For Loop or something similar that will make the process more efficient, and so that I don't have write 20 different variable correlations for each of the 93 counties.

When I run the following in R, it doesn't give an error, but it doesn't give me the response I was hoping for either. Rather than the Spearman's Correlation for  each county, it seems to be ignoring the loop portion and just giving me the correlation between the two variables for ALL counties.

```
    CorrData<-read.csv("H:\\CorrelationData_Master_Regression.csv")
     for (i in CorrData$CountyName)
     {
     dzCasesYears<-cor.test(CorrData$NumVisit, CorrData$dzdx, 
     method="spearman")
     }
```

A very small sample of my data looks similar to this:

```
CountyName  Year    NumVisits        dzdx
Adams       2010    4.545454545      1.19           
Adams       2011    20.83333333      0.20           
Elmore      2010    26.92307692      0.24       
Elmore      2011    0                0.61           
Brown       2010    0               -1.16           
Brown       2011    17.14285714     -1.28           
Clark       2010    25              -1.02           
Clark       2011    0                1.13           
Cass        2010    17.85714286      0.50       
Cass        2011    27.55102041      0.11
```

I have tried to find a similar example online, but am not having luck!

Thank you in advance for all your help!

Comment: Use `dput()` to write out your dataframe as actual R commands we can reoproduce.

Comment: Guys, he's just not using the iterator in his loop code. 'i' is just not used although looped through (cf. my answer below)

Comment: @AP25 yes I saw that immediately. Better to get reproducible data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looping but not using your iterator 'i' in your code. If this makes sense with respect with what you want to do (and judging from your condition). Based on comments, you might want to make sure you are using numerics. Also, i noticed that you are not iterating into your output cor.test vector. I'm not sure a loop is the most efficient way to do it, but it will be just fine and since your started with a loop, You should have something of the kind:

```
 dzCasesYears = list() #Prep a list to store your corr.test results
 counter = 0 # To store your corr.test into list through iterating

 for (i in unique(CorrData$CountyName))
 {
 counter = counter + 1
 # Creating new variables makes the code clearer
 x = as.numeric(CorrData[CorrData$CountyName == i,]$NumVisit)
 y = as.numeric(CorrData[CorrData$CountyName == i,]$dzdx)

 dzCasesYears[[counter]] <-cor.test(x,y,method="spearman")

 }
```

And it's always good to put a unique there when you are iterating.

Comment: Hi AP25, Thank you for your answer. This is great! Could you elaborate on the purpose of the unique?  I hadn't seen that in my searches to figure this out, but am keen to learn about it! Additionally, when I run the code, I get NA results as in my following comment.  Do you have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: S = NA, p-value = NA
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
rho 
 NA

Comment: Not sure without having your datatset. First of all, did you make sure to loop using the subsetting by 'i' as I suggested in my answer ? Second, I always add 'as.numeric' to everything I put into a cor.test, are you sure your columns are encoded to 'numeric' ? Unique sends back a vector which contains one and only one value for each identical values. Basically, in your case, if you do not ask for looping over unique(df$name) you will loop twice over a specific name. I'll edit a bit my answer

Comment: I did make sure to follow your code precisely! I am not sure, but I seemed to fix the error. They were coded as numerics, but I will make sure to use as.numeric in the future to save myself from any issues.  Currently, the loop is stopping at the 4th observation when it should re-iterate through 93 counties. The error is <<4: In cor(rank(x), rank(y)) : the standard deviation is zero. I have included an na.action>> Knowing that you don't have my data in front of you, do you have any recommendations on how to potentially solve this?

Comment: it either means that there is only one value for each and therefore no SD can be computed or that there is no variance in one of your group (all the values are the same, and therefore, following the formula of the cor test, you are dividing by 0 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient)

Comment: That makes sense. I checked it out and that is indeed the case.  Is there a way to coerce the loop to continue with the remaining observations-- or should I manage the data first and then run the loop? Thank you again for all your help--I appreciate it!

Comment: I fixed the error! I re-coded the dataframe to have 0's in place of NA's and the loop continued through all the observations. There was another error that I missed: "not enough finite observations" at the top of the output. Thank you again for all your help @AP25! I have marked your answer as correct!

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` makes operations like this very simple.

```
library('data.table')
CorrData <- as.data.table(read.csv("H:\\CorrelationData_Master_Regression.csv"))
CorrData[, cor(dzdx, NumVisits), CountyName]
```

With the sample data, it's all negative ones because there's two points per county and so the correlation is perfect.  The full dataset should be more interesting!

```
   CountyName V1
1:      Adams -1
2:     Elmore -1
3:      Brown -1
4:      Clark -1
5:       Cass -1
```

**Edit to include p values from cor.test as OP asked in the comment**
This is also quite simple!

```
CorrData[, .(cor=cor(dzdx, NumVisits),
             p=cor.test(dzdx, NumVisits)$p.value),
             CountyName]
```

...But it won't work with your sample data as two points per county is not enough for cor.test to get a p value.  Perhaps you could take @smci's advice and `dput` a larger subset of the data to make your question truly reproducible

Comment: Hi HarlandMason, Thank you for your answer! This is much more simplistic! When I use your code I get this error: Error in drop && !has.j : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'.  Do you have any ideas what could be causing it? Also, would it be possible to use cor.test rather than cor() and to specify the method as well? I am hoping to get the p-value that cor.test() gives.

Comment: I googled that error message and it seems to come up when subsetting is performed improperly, but without your full code and dataset it's very hard to know what exactly is the problem.  I turned your sample data into a .csv, read that into a datable and ran my code to produce the output I shared.  Does it work for you with just the sample data, or does that also throw an error?

Comment: Thank you for all your help! I found this reference to assist with the method change:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078576/data-table-with-cor-test-by-group

Comment: I noticed in going back that all my estimates and p-values are the exact same for all 93 of the counties. When I ran a sample of the correlation tests individually, the results are different. I have cleared my R environment and restarted to assure it's not a data set issue. Do you have any ideas? Thank you again!

Comment: It's very very difficult to diagnose without seeing your code and data.  When I run it with dummy data, I see differing values by county.  In the code I sent, CorrData[, .(cor=cor(dzdx, NumVisits), p=cor.test(dzdx, NumVisits)$p.value), CountyName] that last "CountyName" is what tells data.table to operate on each County independently.  One step you could do to diagnose is figure out where the repeated values are coming from.  Is it what you get when you run the test irrespective of county?  Or is it what you get for one single specific county?

Comment: @HarlandMason Is there a way to do this "for loop" thing by year? In this persons example, it would still produce a correlation value between dzdx and NumVisits, but would do that correlation for each year?

Comment: @Kerry, yep, it will operate "by" whatever you put in that third position, so instead of `CountyName`, it becomes `.(CountyName, Year)`

Comment: However, if you do that with his sample data, I think you'll get an error or a bunch of NAs, since there's only one datapoint per county/year combo, and hence no ability to calculate correlation